# AWS Mythical Mysfits - python errors with locate of package and executable. Amazon needs to update the tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloud9

My question is a follow up of the following from @Ethan Davis:
[AWS Mythical Mysfits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433759/aws-mythical-mysfits)

I ran into the same problem. The answer/solution from @Zeitounator resolved it. I expect others studying the tutorial will run into the same until Amazon updates it.

I ran into a problem later, when running the container as part of the local test:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I made one change to the code from @Zeitounator (line 12):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

I rebuilt the container and ran the test with no error:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 221d7a0cdb88
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: What's your question?  With that `ENTRYPOINT`, how do you accommodate running alternate commands, like a debugging shell `docker run --rm -it yourimage bash` or checking the filesystem contents `docker run --rm yourimage ls -l /app`?

Comment: My question was -how to resolve the docker error above. I figured it out. I made a small change to the fix I want to submit a correction to the fix submitted by @Zeitounator. Because I'm a new contributore, I wasn't allowed to -comment- on his fix.